# Is it possible to .getScript from a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want `$.getScript` to load/execute scripts inside a div with the ID "dynamic" from "/footer.html".

```
$("footer").load("/footer.html #dynamic>*", function() {
  $.getScript("/assets/master.js");
});
```

Is it possible to load the content of a specific element (#dynamic) and load/execute scripts inside without having to separate the scripts into a different file, like the code above?

Also, why does #1 load scripts but #2 and #3 does not?

1. `$("footer").load("/footer.html");` loads entire HTML document and its scripts too.
2. `$("footer").load("/footer.html #dynamic");` loads only the "#dynamic" element and all of the content inside except for scripts.
3. `$("footer").load("/footer.html #dynamic>*");` loads only the content of "#dynamic" element but without scripts and the element itself.

I am using #3 because I want the content inside "#dynamic" without the element itself but the problem is that scripts do not load/execute.

Comment: What you want is obviously impossible due to security reasons.

Comment: @freedomn-m good suggestion but the the scripts are direct children of "#dynamic"

Comment: @hindmost then why does #1 load/execute scripts? I'm confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to load the content of a specific element (#dynamic)
>   with the scripts inside without having to separate the scripts into a
>   different file, like the code above?

No. JQuery .load() method discards the scripts without execution if used with the selector expression.

So, I beleive your point 2 is not correct:

> *$("footer").load("/footer.html #dynamic"); loads only the "#dynamic" element and all of the content inside (scripts too).*

Answer (score 2):

From [docs](https://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution):

> When calling `.load()` using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to `.html()` prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If `.load()` is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are *not* executed.